# Acess files with the same name in Sub-Subdirectories

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, nsbundle

First my structure:

```
Application
|---> dirA
    |---> dirB
        |---> index.html 
        |---> somefile.js
    |---> dirC
        |---> index.html 
        |---> somefile.js
    |---> dirD
        |---> index.html 
        |---> somefile.js
```

some problems here. i need to load the index.html of this different dirs in my webview. but i don't know how to get the url for a specific dir, lets say dirB inside dirA and i got a notice `Warning: Multiple build commands for output testo4.app/index.html`. The problem is, i cannot rename the files, for that i created subdirectories (real direcories, not only "groups" from xcode)

thanks for all hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those are real directories, their paths should be `testo4.app/dirA/dirB/index.html`, `testo4.app/dirA/dirC/index.html` and `testo4.app/dirA/dirD/index.html`, shouldn't they?

With the files being inside your bundle, you could use something like

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"index"] ofType:@"html" inDirectory:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dirA/dirB/"]];
```

for the one inside `dirB`, for instance.